# Search Index with Back and Forward buttons to display total Users on table and one with the actual cell

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a search button, that opens a worksheet on another workbook that has a column with "Usernames" on it. As the username will be repeated but the other values won't, i want to display two textboxes. 
One for the total number of rows in the sheet with that actual Username. And one that displays the current row that is displayed. 
For example I have 10 Usernames called: Santiago. So i want two boxes: the first to display the current cell (should be the first value searched) and the other with the total of rows with that username.

Using the buttons back and forward, the current cell should show -1 or +1 to display how many records are left until the user navigated from all of them.

Currently, i have all the code done, without the current and total values. I tried `Rows.Count` and `Cells("B:B")` but when i click to search for the values, it goes directly to the error handler.

```
Private Sub btnBuscar4_Click()
    'declarar las variables
    Dim FindRow
    Dim cRow As String
    Dim Datos As Worksheet: Set Datos = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\rescariz\Desktop\Plataforma\Datos.xlsx").Worksheets("Datos")
    Dim A As Integer, Count As Integer

    Windows("Datos.xlsx").Visible = False 'Hace que no se muestre el excel externo (Datos)

    'hold in memory and stop screen flicker
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'error block
    On Error GoTo errHandler:

        'Filtrar solo por Apellido
        If Me.BApe3 <> "" Then

        'Encontrar la fila con la data
        cRow = Me.BApe3.Value
        Set FindRow = Datos.Range("B:B").Find(What:=cRow, LookIn:=xlValues)
        Me.CurrentAddress = FindRow.Address 'te trae la celda actual

        For A = 1 To Rows("B2:B500")
        If FindRow = cRow Then
        Count = Count + 1
        End If
        Next A

        Reg2.Value = Count

        'agregar los valores a las casillas correspondientes
        Leg3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, -1)
        Fech3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 3)
        Ape3.Value = FindRow
        Nomb3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 1)
        Pues3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 2)
        ComboLiqui3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 4)
        FechaDesde3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 5)
        FechaHasta3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 6)
        Dia3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 11)
        Dia4.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 12)
        Cant3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 7)
        Obs3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 8)

    Else
        MsgBox "Por favor, ingresar un Legajo o un Apellido"
    End If

    'error block
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub
errHandler:
    MsgBox "Error! Verificar los datos ingresados, porque no son correctos!" & vbCrLf & Err.Description

End Sub
```

```
'Previous Value
Private Sub bsReg1_Click()
Dim Datos As Worksheet
Dim bRow As String
Dim FindRow As Range

Set Datos = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\rescariz\Desktop\Plataforma\Datos.xlsx").Worksheets("Datos")

If Me.BLeg3.Value <> "" Or Me.BLeg3.Value <> "" And Me.BApe3.Value <> "" Then
MsgBox "No se puede realizar la busqueda con Legajo"

Else
bRow = Me.BApe3.Value

Set FindRow = Datos.Range("B:B").Find(What:=bRow, After:=Range(Me.CurrentAddress), SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues)
Me.CurrentAddress = FindRow.Address 'te trae la celda actual

'agregar los valores a las casillas correspondientes
        Me.Leg3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, -1)
        Me.Fech3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 3)
        Me.Ape3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 0)
        Me.Nomb3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 1)
        Me.Pues3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 2)
        Me.ComboLiqui3 = FindRow.Offset(0, 4)
        Me.FechaDesde3 = FindRow.Offset(0, 5)
        Me.FechaHasta3 = FindRow.Offset(0, 6)
        Me.Cant3 = FindRow.Offset(0, 7)
        Me.Obs3 = FindRow.Offset(0, 8)

End If
Exit Sub
End Sub
```

```
'Next Value
Private Sub bsReg2_Click()
Dim Datos As Worksheet
Dim bRow As String
Dim FindRow As Range

Set Datos = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\rescariz\Desktop\Plataforma\Datos.xlsx").Worksheets("Datos")

If Me.BLeg3.Value <> "" Or Me.BLeg3.Value <> "" And Me.BApe3.Value <> "" Then
MsgBox "No se puede realizar la busqueda con Legajo"

Else
bRow = Me.BApe3.Value

Set FindRow = Datos.Range("B:B").Find(What:=bRow, After:=Range(Me.CurrentAddress), SearchDirection:=xlNext, LookIn:=xlValues)
Me.CurrentAddress = FindRow.Address 'te trae la celda actual

'agregar los valores a las casillas correspondientes
        Me.Leg3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, -1)
        Me.Fech3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 3)
        Me.Ape3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 0)
        Me.Nomb3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 1)
        Me.Pues3.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 2)
        Me.ComboLiqui3 = FindRow.Offset(0, 4)
        Me.FechaDesde3 = FindRow.Offset(0, 5)
        Me.FechaHasta3 = FindRow.Offset(0, 6)
        Me.Cant3 = FindRow.Offset(0, 7)
        Me.Obs3 = FindRow.Offset(0, 8)
End If
Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: Has this question been answered by your later 2 questions ?

Comment: @CDP1802 I manage to make the total rows show when its filtered, but the problem i need is to loop in the following way. If im on position 1, and the user wants to go to the last row, it doesn´t do that, because i just added to show +1 or -1 when the left or right button is clicked.

Comment: OK which  question do you want me to answer first ?

Comment: I'm looking forward first to use the best and easiest way to filter and then clear that filter, so i don´t have any future problems with it. Afterwards, to be able to show which cell its positioned and that the user can go backwards and forwards with no limitations if possible